# Function signature indicates return type void*, but returns pointer of a different type

Tags: c, pointers

I'm confused about the following code, with the function signature indicating the function returns a void pointer. The type actually returned however, is BlockInfo*. The function searches the first free memory block of size reqSize in a list. The whole program compiles and runs correctly.

```
static void * searchFreeList(size_t reqSize) {
  BlockInfo* freeBlock;

  freeBlock = FREE_LIST_HEAD;
  while (freeBlock != NULL){
    if (SIZE(freeBlock->sizeAndTags) >= reqSize) {
      return freeBlock;
    } else {
      freeBlock = freeBlock->next;
      }
  }
  return NULL;
```

}

My questions are:
(1) Why is `return freeBlock`,which returns type BlockInfo* a valid statement.
(2) For a function that returns void pointer, when its return value is assigned to another pointer variable, e.g.:

```
int * ptr;  // Or double* ptr, etc.
ptr = searchFreeList(someSize);
```

Are these valid assignments?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `void*` : the swiss-army-knife of ***data*** pointers in C.

Comment: `void*` is a generic pointer that can point to anything.

Comment: All pointers are of same size, which is `sizeof(void *)`, try printing `sizeof(freeBlock);`.  Side question: have you ever asked yourself why `malloc` and family return `void *`?

Comment: @user9000 Not true. Only `char*` pointer is required to have same presentation as `void*`. All data pointers can be *converted* to `void*`, but their sizes can differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is return freeBlock,which returns type BlockInfo* a valid statement.

`void *` is a generic pointer type and is guaranteed to hold any object pointer type. There is an implicit conversion between all object pointer types to `void *` so no cast is even needed in the return statement.

> int * ptr;  // Or double* ptr, etc.
>   ptr = searchFreeList(someSize);
>   Are these valid assignments?

Yes, they are valid assignments but dereferencing the pointer may be then undefined behavior if the underlying type was a different type.

For example:

```
char a = 42;
void *p = &a;
int *q = p;

*q;  // undefined behavior
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, `void *` is a generic pointer type. It can point to any pointer type. So,

```
ptr = searchFreeList(someSize);
```

is a valid assignment.

Answer (score 0):

A `void` pointer can store address of any type and in this case it is storing address of type `BlockInfo`. So when a function returns a pointer of type `BlockInfo` it is totally fine because the prototype doesn't care for the type in this case.

The second part of your question where you ask whether

```
int *ptr = searchFreeList(someSize);
```

is valid. Yes

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) *2);
```

is valid , here `malloc()` returns `void *`

The result will be that pointer of type int pointing to some struct and dereferencing it will be UB